# PHP Sum Of Mysql row value

Tags: php, mysql, addition

```
figure 1. sum all value of money   
    id  date           name     money //sample items only
    1   March 5 2014   matt      50 //records to add
    2   March 5 2014   john      10 //records to add
    3   March 2 2014   matt      50 //records to add

figure 2. sum all value of money when search matt
    id  date           name     money //sample items only
    1   March 5 2014   matt      50 //records to add
    2   March 5 2014   john      10
    3   March 2 2014   matt      50 //records to add
```

Hi guys can you help me i dont know the code how to Add the rows value in my sql database.(see sample above)

i have this code which will count how many records i have

```
<input type="text" name="namesearch" size="5"  tabindex="1" />

<input type="submit" name='click' value='Search' />


if(isset($_POST['click'])){


    $name= $_POST['namesearch'];
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table WHERE name='$name'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    $values = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    $num_item= $values['total']; 
    echo "Number of Records Found # ".$num_item;
```

Comment: what you tried in your query?

Comment: mysql_num_rows($result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this as query

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(money) AS total_money FROM table WHERE name='$name'";
```

use this to view the result

```
$num_item = $values['total']; 
$total_value = $values['total_money'];
echo "Number of Records Found # ".$num_item;
echo "Total Money ".$total_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my MySQL server is missing after an OS upgrade, don't trust the syntax (lol). Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(`money`) AS `total_money` FROM `my_table` GROUP BY `name`;
```

This should(?) give you the count of rows for each name and it's sum of total money.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MySQL SUM Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

```
SELECT SUM(money) AS total FROM table WHERE name='$name'
```